# How to properly light a Son Of Hibachi

Tags: camping, grilling

So my friend convinced me to buy a [Son Of Hibachi](http://www.sonofhibachi.com) :) I've set it up and want to give it a try in the evening. Of course there are several sources for a "how to" and even videos but I wanted instructions from "in the field" experiences.

So what are the basic steps to light a Son Of Hibatchi and are there any practical tips and tricks?

---

**Edit**:

Quick overview of the grill

[image: Son Of Hibachi]

Comment: @OddDeer I see you never got an answer on these questions. If you have good experience of them, you could self-answer if you want.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Good idea :)

Answer (score 3):

I’ve been using this grill for a few years now whenever I go outside to a park or something. It works great and to get it going you put it in vertical position, put the top lid on opened about 30-50 % and put some (not too little!) starter stuff in the cup underneath. (I use those curly wooden things since they don’t give any nasty taste or smell)

Light the starter stuff and close the cup for like 90% so a little air can still get in from underneath.

I take my time getting it started because grilling works a lot better when the coals are glowing good hot before you start using it.

Answer (score 1):

From the "quick overview" it looks like the charcoal is started in the closed vertical position, which should get all the coals hot fairly quickly.

And indeed, the process can be seen on YouTube:

https://youtu.be/cXOxQME5w4c