# Which characteristics to look for in charcoal for a Son Of Hibachi portable grill?

Tags: camping, grilling

In addition to my [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13601/how-to-properly-enlighten-a-son-of-hibatchi) about how to light a Son of Hibachi portable grill, I want to know which charcoals I should get. Which characteristics should I have an eye on?

Answer (score 3):

From experience, self-lighting treated charcoals give a bad flavor to the food, as do liquid lighters. I used to use a stack in a metal chimney to light. Always use the freshest and very dry charcoal if possible. The flavor might be better depending on the type of wood its from. Smaller pieces will light faster and give more heat quicker. Large ones will burn longer.

Comment: Spaces after punctuation help with readability (I wonder why the markup generation doesn't automatically take care of this, just like with double spaces).